# How do I get the full-format name of a Java version?

Tags: java, version, launch4j

I created a Java application. I'm trying to use Launch4j to wrap the JAR file in a EXE file.

But Launch4j won't make the EXE unless I tell it the minimum JRE version required, in this exact format: x.x.x[_xx].

How can I get this full-format name of a version of Java? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run java with the `-version` parameter;

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the full version of version 1.2?

Comment: Maybe it's silly, but can I know for sure that the full format for 1.2.0 is 1.2.0_00 ? Maybe they started with 1.2.0_01 or something? I'm saying this because I don't know how Launcher4j works, so maybe if this version never existed it's going to be a problem or something.